# ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 100, 6) are incompatible

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to solve a classification problem using LSTM Sequential machine learning. My DataFrame structure is here:

> feature1, feature2, feature3, category

[image]

features are accelerometer sensor data point in float and category is label for activity classes (values 0~5)

I have splitted train and test data with,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_columns = acc.iloc[:, 0:3]
y_columns = acc.iloc[:, 3:4]

trainx, testx, trainy, testy = train_test_split(x_columns, y_columns, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
assert(len(trainx) == len(trainy))
```

I have also prepared sequence as the data are time correlated.

```
from scipy.stats import mode

window_len = 100
stride_len = 10

def sequence_generator(x, y, length, stride):
    seq_x = []
    seq_y = []
    data_length = len(x)

    for i in range(0, data_length - length + 1, stride):
        input_sequence = x.iloc[i : i + length]
        target_sequence = y.iloc[i : i + length]
        target_mode = mode(target_sequence.values)[0][0]
        seq_x.append(input_sequence)
        seq_y.append(target_mode)
    return np.array(seq_x), np.array(seq_y)

tx, ty = sequence_generator(trainx, trainy, window_len, stride_len)
vx, vy = sequence_generator(testx, testy, window_len, stride_len)
```

I have also hot encoded the target column,

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

tty = to_categorical(ty, num_classes=len(set(ty))) # num_classes = 6
vvy = to_categorical(vy, num_classes=len(set(ty)))
```

Here are some output at that point that may help you to identify my problem:

> tx.shape = (113020, 100, 3)

> ty.shape = (113020, 6)

> set(ty) = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

[image]

At this point, I have defined my model architecture. **Please ignore about the accuracy of the model because I am using it just for learning purpose.**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.utils import to_categorical

n_class = len(set(ty)) # 6
n_features = len(x_columns.columns) # 3

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Input((window_len, n_features)))
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dense(n_class, activation='softmax'))
model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#history = model2.fit(tx, ty, epochs=5)
history = model2.fit(tx, tty, epochs=5)
```

When I run, following error occured. What am I missing?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[246], line 19
     17 model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
     18 #history = model2.fit(tx, ty, epochs=5)
---> 19 history = model2.fit(tx, tty, epochs=5)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /tmp/__autograph_generated_filefn9kd22q.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1377, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1360, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1349, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1127, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1185, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 277, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 143, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 270, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 2221, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/Users/hissain/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5575, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 6) and (None, 100, 6) are incompatible
```

**Update 1:**

As Joe suggested in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77381158/valueerror-shapes-none-and-none-100-6-are-incompatible?noredirect=1#comment136418606_77381158) to use a Flatten layer, I have added one, but no luck.

Comment: I certainly don't know for sure, but from reading [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) it seems like maybe your input being 2-D is making your output (batch_size, 100, 6) instead of (batch_size, 6). Maybe you need to flatten your input?

Comment: @Joe could you please explain with code? Thank in advance.

Comment: I'm suggesting adding `model.add(Flatten())` between the input and the first dense layer, as in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten), but I don't know if that's right for what you're doing.  I've never used LSTMs. Then again, I don't see where you're actually using them either. Your model looks like a simple FFNN to me.

Comment: @Joe thanks for your suggestion. I have added a Flatten() layer as you suggested but no luck. Could it be that my sequence generating function is wrong?

Comment: @Joe I am sorry for my previous response. The problem is solved when I add a Flatten layer as you suggested. Thanks. You can add couple of lines and post Answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm still not sure it's the right approach. Are you trying to use an LSTM, as you mentioned? For an LSTM maybe you shouldn't flatten. But you haven't used LSTM in your code.

Comment: @Joe here is the full code ( https://github.com/hissain/ml/blob/main/HAR_using_LSTM.ipynb ) that worked. I used LSTM layer there and it shows around 99% accuracy. I don’t know how come. Could you please see what’s wrong?

Comment: I don't know because I'm not familiar with LSTM. However, why is 99% accuracy a problem?

Comment: @Joe its ok. Actually, I have randomly added some layers without even carefully analysing the data and it turns 99% accuracy. I am concerned if the model is fit properly or not. Besides I used flatten layer after LSTM which you suspected wrong. Anyway, thanks for your time.